# Do we have an understanding of the universe?

Tags: truth, human-condition

My question is if we as rational creatures have come to terms that the universe is huge, there are planets bigger than earth, and with the advance of string theory, have we as humans finally have a grasp on what are we doing here? Why yes or not yet? Thanks

Comment: This question is overly vague. Please refine your question to a specific area of human understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend to read [this short article by Asimov](http://hermiene.net/essays-trans/relativity_of_wrong.html) about the nature of scientific understanding. Hopefully that would resolve the questions about the **final** understanding of nature.

Comment: On that note, there are a bunch of great Youtube videos of Richard Feynman out there on the subject of the nature of science. E.g., [The Pleasure of Finding Things Out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bgaw9qe7DEE).

Comment: I like more the video of Leonard Krauss http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUH77mYBUtM that is excellent